# Create float from exponent and significand

Tags: go, floating-point, binary

Given integers `exp` and `0<=sig<2^52`, how can I create the float64 with `exp` as exponent and whose significand bits are the same as the binary representation of `sig` (in Go)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IEEE-754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines the floating point arithmetics which Go uses for floating point numbers such as `float32` and `float64` (just like almost any other language).

Since your significand may be up to 52 bits, obviously it can only be represented using a `float64` value.

The memory layout (bits) of a `float64` value is described in [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Here's a picture of the bits of a `float64` value (taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

You claim you have the exponent value and the significand (which is the fraction part).

You may use simple bitwise arithmetic to construct the 64-bit value of the floating point like this:

```
bits := exp<<52 | sig
```

(Note: `exp` and `sig` should be of type `uint64`. If not, use a type conversion.)

Once you have the bits, you may use the [`math.Float64frombits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64frombits) function to get it as a `float64` value:

```
f := math.Float64frombits(bits)
```

Note that the exponent value of the memory layout is not the "direct" number you have to use when calculating the value of the number, but:

> The double-precision binary floating-point exponent is encoded using an [offset-binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset-binary) representation, with the zero offset being 1023; also known as exponent bias in the IEEE 754 standard.

So the number encoded in the above double-precision format is calculated like:

> (-1)<sup>sign</sup> x 2<sup>e-1023</sup> x 1.fraction

Comment: Would `Math.Ldexp` help here?  `func Ldexp(frac float64, exp int) float64`

Comment: @aMike I was considering it, but it takes the fraction as a `float64` value, and it does something similar under the hood.

Comment: I see, so if I want the actual exponent to be `exp`, I have to do `bits := (exp+1023)<<52 | sig`, correct?